# Относительный путь к юниту Turbo Pascal

Tags: pascal, импорт, include, freepascal, turbopascal

Как указать в online compiler pascal и или включить юнит Graph?
А также где взять в интернете юнит sysutils?
Какой online compiler pascal поддерживает Graph?

Comment: Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме.

Comment: Вряд ли это возможно. Какая вообще задача стоит? Для чего понадобилось онлайн турбу запускать?